# hybrid_command dont appears in discord (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, command

i made a discord bot in python and im trying to use slash_commands for the first time.

My VSC does not show errors but when i see the command in discord it does not exist.

Maybe it takes time to load? i dont know.

this is my main.py:

```
import discord
from discord import Client, Intents
from discord.ext import commands

intents = Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)

bot.remove_command('hola')

@bot.command(name="hola", description="test")
async def hola(ctx: discord.Message, x: str):
    await ctx.reply(x)

    
@bot.hybrid_command(name="pvp_winner_embed", description="test")
async def pvp_winner_embed(ctx: discord.Message, player1, player2, player3):
    await ctx.reply(player1)
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=1025499163217113178))
    print(f'Logged as {bot.user}')
    
bot.run('')
```